# Correlating movement patterns of IDs in time

Tags: pandas, time-series, coordinates, correlation, pairing

I have some x-, y- coordinates per ID and used the groupby('ID').diff() functions to subtract the differences between x and y coordinates in order to identify directions patterns / individual ID.
If the directions (xx and yy) are around 0, then the ID didn't move. Now, how can I find the correlations between the different IDs and their directions? Ideally, I would like to pair the IDs that move towards each other, and the IDs that sit "silent". Any help is deeply appreciated!!!

```
ID      Time                    X   Y   xx  yy
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.255 225 235 1.0 1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.255 257 232 -1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.495 226 235 1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.495 257 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.733 226 235 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.733 257 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.008 224 234 -2.0 -1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.008 258 232 1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.255 225 235 1.0 1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.255 257 232 -1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.495 226 235 1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.495 257 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:00.733 226 235 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:00.733 257 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:01.009 224 235 -2.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:01.009 258 232 1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:01.371 225 235 1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:01.371 259 232 1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:01.611 226 235 1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:01.611 258 232 -1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:01.736 226 235 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:01.736 258 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:02.066 226 235 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:02.066 259 232 1.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:02.281 226 234 0.0 -1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:02.281 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:02.568 226 234 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:02.568 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:02.769 225 234 -1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:02.769 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:03.010 225 234 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:03.010 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:03.242 225 233 0.0 -1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:03.242 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:03.574 225 235 0.0 2.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:03.574 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:03.760 224 235 -1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:03.760 259 231 0.0 -1.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:03.971 224 234 0.0 -1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:03.971 259 232 0.0 1.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:04.231 224 234 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:04.231 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:04.567 224 234 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:04.567 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:04.849 223 234 -1.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:04.849 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:05.054 223 234 0.0 0.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:05.054 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:05.288 224 235 1.0 1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:05.288 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:05.597 225 234 1.0 -1.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:05.597 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:05.783 222 232 -3.0 -2.0
42386   2019-07-24 08:00:05.783 259 232 0.0 0.0
42403   2019-07-24 08:00:06.014 222 233 0.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first get the values over which you want to compute your correlations in columns and then use the already implemented method of pandas **.corr()**. So for it an unstack method is an easy approach.

Here you have my code:

```
# considering that the position measures are already sorted we will create indexes for every step and call them 'measure'
df['measure'] = [_ // 2 for _ in range(len(df))] # 2 IDs in total
# no more need of time data
df.drop(labels='Time', axis=1, inplace=True)

# this line of work does all the work. I am using the .corr() method from pandas
df.set_index(['ID', 'measure']).unstack('ID').corr()
```

The output should be a correlations matrix, I used a fancy method to produce this heatmap using seaborn:

[image]

If you are interested on the visualisation as well, take a look to the heatmap method from seaborn.

Comment: Thank you so much oso_ted. This is great. Do you have an idea of how to make these correlation with time as variable? Is there a way to split the data up into seconds or minutes and see how the the id's correlate in time?

Comment: You can build a 3 dimensions matrix where the third one will be the time (a temporal space). THen to check if movement in different axis correlates along the time, you can compute a mean and a standard deviation over the time axis. Hope this will help. Can you please select my response to your previous question as a good answer? This will add points to my profile